# With Laravel 4 is there a way to stop it from creating a session when a user access a page?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have notice that every time I load a page for the first time (new user) it creates a new session. I want to disable that. I want the creation of a session only when a user logins in.

So is there a way to tell Laravel 4 not to create a new session every time a new person comes to the website?

Comment: Are you sure it's session. To me it looks more like cookie. Besides why do you want to do that?

Comment: For performance gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the session driver to a blank string to prevent Laravel from creating a session

```
Config::set('session.driver','');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 4.1 Dimirc answer does not seem to work for two reasons, firstly an error is thrown with the unknown session driver, and second sessions are started very early on in Laravel so changing the session driver needs to occur early.

I am currently fighting this same problem and have found I can change the session driver before the session starts in bootstrap/start.php line 61.

At this point the framework has loaded a lot of the Laravel functionality, but not yet the sessions.

You can access the Request Class and check the user is on the page you want to block sessions like so:

```
require $framework.'/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php';

if ($app['request']->getMethod() == 'GET' && $app['request']->path() == '/')
{
    $app['config']->set('session.driver', 'array');
}
```

(the first line is line 60 of bootstrap/start.php depending on any environment detection in place).

Note I am setting the session driver to array as this driver does not persist data between requests.

Hope this helps!